# Writing a proxy using sockets

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

I'm writing a HTTP proxy server using sockets, now the program is receiving the request successfully but I'm not able to get it back again to the browser...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.*;


public class Server {


public void startServer() {
    final ExecutorService clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(80);
                while (true) {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
    serverThread.start();

}

private class ClientTask implements Runnable {
    private Socket clientSocket;

    private ClientTask(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            // Read request
            InputStream incommingIS = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[8196];
            int len = incommingIS.read(b);

            if (len > 0) {
                System.out.println("REQUEST"
                        + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "-------");
                System.out.println(new String(b, 0, len));

                // Write request
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 80);
                OutputStream outgoingOS = socket.getOutputStream();
                outgoingOS.write(b, 0, len);

                // Copy response
                OutputStream incommingOS = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                InputStream outgoingIS = socket.getInputStream();
                for (int length; (length = outgoingIS.read(b)) != -1;) {
                    incommingOS.write(b, 0, length);
                }

                incommingOS.close();
                outgoingIS.close();
                outgoingOS.close();
                incommingIS.close();

                socket.close();
            } else {
                incommingIS.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

What I'm doing wrong? Anyone could help me on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming you got the entire request in a single read, instead of using a loop like your response loop.

You're  also assuming that it is terminated by an end of stream, which means the client must have done a shutdownOutput(), which doesn't happen in most protocols.

In general this isn't the correct technique for writing a proxy. You need to start two threads per client, to copy data in both directions simultaneously, and defer closing the socket until you've read EOS from both directions.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean when you say copy the data in both directions? I don't understand how I should do this...

Comment: I told you. With two threads per connection. One to copy in one direction, one in the other.